# Creating math formulas in convert PDF files (where input is website)

Tags: pdf, math, latex, formula, mathjax

I am using MathJax in my website to create math formulas and it's working great.

I need a way to output those formulas into PDF documents generated by my server.

I'm currently using a Windows server and backend is PHP.

I'm using TCPDF to create my PDF files, but I cant find any way to get my math formulas into those PDFs, be cause the math formulas are stored in my database in TeX format.

Is there anyway to convert them to math formulas before I insert them into my document?

At first I tried to use the SVG output format from MathJax and somehow extract that output, save it in my database and use that with *TCPDF*, but apparently it is not good enough because the SVG output from MathJax isn't only SVG.

I have looked for online tools to convert my TeX formulas into images, but I didn't find any site that provides an API for that. So I looked for a command line tool, but it seems like most (or all of them) are for Linux systems only.

I tried [this one, tex2png](http://www.nawouak.net/?cat=informatics.tex2png+lang=en),
but it didnt work :

[image]

BTW, I don't have Latex installed. Do I need to install in order to use tex2png?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a website with MathJax-based formulas to play with? *(I have an idea about how to convert the page to PDFs containing the formulas, but need to test it first...)*

Comment: well this site  has mathJax based-formulas..in the math forum http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Look. I'm going to do some research to find an answer for you. I ***do*** have these skills. But I'm not going to waste my time in searching for suitable examples. Today I do ***not*** feel that amount of eagerness in me. So if ***you*** don't want to do it: just leave it and be happy. Have a good day!

Comment: You should also provide a link to ***(1)*** the resulting PNG generated with your *tex2png*, ***(2)*** the resulting PDF generated with your TCPDF from the website you provide as an example.

Comment: 1. as I said , the tex2ong isnt working for me, the command gets stuck at the position i showed , (2) i dont think the pdf genrated is relevnt cause I'm looking for a way to convert the tex to image 3.I'm not sure what you mean by a website with mathjax maybe this is a good site to see how it works http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php (4) I think I found a solution by installing miktex on my server and using latex2pdf commandline tool, I'm now struggling with combininig hebrew and english togheter, so if you come up with a better or easier solution that will be great Th alot!

Comment: *"I'm not sure what you mean by a website with mathjax"*... Well, it was ***you*** who mentioned in the OP ***"using MathJax in my website to create math formulas"***...

Comment: *"i dont think the pdf genrated is relevnt cause I'm looking for a way to convert the tex to image"*... It was also ***you***, who wrote in the OP: ***"I need a way to output those formulas into PDF documents generated by my server."*** -- So, what gives? Please think about what exactly your goal and your problem is, what question you have about it, then edit your OP accordingly.

Comment: ok, so what I'm trying to accomplish is having formulas written using mathjax to be inserted into a pdf document, this site http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php is a good example. my site is pretty similiar, u write formulas using $$ and they get rendered in web view, i want to achive the same or similar output in my pdf using the same input. for now it looks like the best way to do it is to convert the formula into pdf using miktex, i can then manupulate that pdf and put it the way i want it in my final pdf.